# HTTP/2 stream was not closed for long User-Agents

Tags: sockets, curl, https, http2, webrequest

I am running into this issue. I'm executing `curl` on a site with different user agents, and I noticed that for some of them, it closed the HTTP request with an error.

This might seem an issue with the length of the user agent but it works with random longer strings.

To reproduce:

`curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.94 Chrome/37.0.2062.94" https://property-nicaragua.com`

But it works with (notice the trim User agent):

`curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.94 Chrome/37" https://property-nicaragua.com`

Comment: And your question is what? An explanation why this happens (who knows - it's the server which behaves differently), a way to fix the server in case its yours, .... ?

Comment: Server is not under my control, just wanted to see what are the usually culprit on such cases!

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't like one of your user-agents for some silly reason. Maybe there's a bug in the server. Maybe it crashed.